# Alignment of negative numbers in Fast Reports

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am using Fast Reports Embarcadero Edition 5.0 with Delphi Pro 10 Seattle.  I have created a report with a currency field that contains both positive and negative values.  I set the displayformat based on US standards: kind is fkNumber, decimalsepartor is ".", thousandseparator is "," and Formatstr is %2.2m. Regardless of how I set the alignment property, the decimal point in negative numbers do not line up with positive numbers.  The minus sign pushes negative numbers one character to the right.  How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

After posting the question, I found an answer.  Fast Reports Text Objects have two alignment properties: Alignment which is the object itself and HAlign, a subproperty  of the Object's Frame property.  Alignment controls general alignment and HAlign controls how the number lines up within the object frame.  After setting it to haRight, the report formatted correctly.